# Unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurpe

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I am getting the following error messages returned:

```
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script3.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurpe @ line 1, column 1. import groovy.json.JsonSlurpe ^ 
    org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurpe @ line 1, column 1. at 
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:149) at 
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1225) at 
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:178) at 
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$11.call(CompilationUnit.java:651) at 
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931) at 
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593) at 
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:542) at
```

Comment: Can you show your script please? And error in line 1? see if there are any invisible characters.

Comment: Why hello there, welcome to SO. It's a great resource for coding problems and so forth, but it's important to format your questions correctly. I edited your question for clarity and readability. As a rule of thumb it's good to post what code you have already tried to solve your problem. You have access to some of the best coders in the world on here (for free!) but we have to keep the community spick and span :D

Comment: Deepika, have you got chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 23):

Try changing the first line. Trivial typo.

**From:**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurpe
```

**To:**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line should be like this...

import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have `groovy.json` on class path, e.g. depend on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
</dependency>
```